# How to unescape html (in String) in Koreander templates?

Tags: string, kotlin, escaping, rendering, html-escape

I am using [lukasjapan/koreander](https://github.com/lukasjapan/koreander) library along with its ktor-support version, and when I call ViewModel(Res class) topbar variable from in kor file, it escapes the html String.

**This is how I'm calling ktor to serve web-pages:**

```kotlin
suspend fun main() = coroutineScope<Unit> {
    System.setProperty(SimpleLogger.DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL_KEY, "TRACE")
    embeddedServer(
        Netty,
        port = 80,
        module = Application::module
    ).apply { start(wait = true) }
}

data class Res(val topbar: String)

fun Application.module() {
    install(KoreanderFeature)
    routing {
        get("/") {
            val text = javaClass.getResource("/templates/topbar.kor").readText()
            val resource = Res(Koreander().render(text, Any()))
            call.respondKorRes("/templates/index.kor", resource)
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my topbar.kor file:** This is just for testing so i make it just small.

```
.navbar-custom
    %ul.list-unstyled.topnav-menu.float-right.mb-0
        %li.d-none.d-sm-block
            %form.app-search
```

**This is my index.kor file:**

```
%html
    %head
    %body
        %p.hello Hello World!
        $topbar / <- problem here, this has escaped html, browser interpret it as text
```

**This is what rendered on the browser:**
[image: Browser-snapshot]
How do I unescape the html here so that browser interpret it as a valid html and render it on there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from David Eriksson @ official [kotlinlang-slack](https://kotlinlang.slack.com)

We can use `:unsafehtml` filter to effectively bypass HTML escaping:

```
%html
    %head
    %body
        %p.hello Hello World!
        :unsafehtml $topbar
```